Find the highest amount of money a shopkeeper can make through a certain number of sales
I did a coding problem for a job interview recently where I got the right results, but my code wasn't fast enough and they didn't tell me why.
Imagine there's a greedy shopkeeper who has a bunch of items and a certain quantity of each item. He sells each item at a price equal to its remaining quantity and he wants to make as much money as possible through a certain number of sales. I think the number of items, the quantity of each item, and the number of sales could each be up to 105? Any solution in Java had to run in less than 4 seconds.
The example given was 5 items with quantities 10, 10, 8, 9, and 1. Through 6 sales, the most money he could make would be 10+10+9+9+9+8=55.
To clarify, it works as follows:
After the first sale, take one of the quantity of 10 items for a price of 10.  Since there are 9 of that item left, the price is now 9 and the remaining items are:
9, 10, 8, 9, 1 with a revenue of 10 after the first sale

continuing in this fashion, each  time taking the priciest item available
9, 9, 8, 9, 1 with a revenue of 20 after 2 sales
8, 9, 8, 9, 1 with a revenue of 29 after 3 sales
8, 8, 8, 9, 1 with a revenue of 38 after 4 sales
8, 8, 8, 9, 1 with a revenue of 47 after 5 sales
7, 8, 8, 9, 1 with a revenue of 55 after 6 sales

The main way I tried was by getting the maximum quantity every time and adding this for the selected number of sales. But for thousands of items, this was too slow. Something like:
public static long getMaximumAmount(List<Integer> arr, int m) {
    long revenue = 0;
    int max = 0;
    while (m>0) {
        max = Collections.max(arr);
        revenue += max;
        arr.set(arr.indexOf(max),max-1);
        m--;
    }
    return revenue;
}

Then I tried sorting the quantities every time and taking the top element that way, but this was also too slow.
Then I tried sorting them once and starting with the top element and comparing with adjacent elements each time to get the max that way, but that was also too slow. EDIT: I think I was close here. You could sort it once, remove the top element, then loop through the remaining elements to find where to re-insert the element minus 1 to keep it sorted.
And finally I tried not sorting it and starting with the first element and comparing with adjacent elements each time to get the higher quantity, but that didn't always get the right results despite being faster.

"The example given was 5 items with quantities 10, 10, 8, 9, and 1. Through 6 sales, the most money he could make would be 10+10+9+9+9+8=55." Why not 10+10+10+10+10+10=60?

Since, except for the last attempt, your program worked, this looks like it would be better asked at Code Review. Please read their How to Ask. Include, in the question, code for your best attempt.

This question should be reopened. Code Review is not what this is about: The code was broken - it did not correctly do what was required. In this specific case, the requirement includes performance. Algorithmic Complexity is entirely within what SO is for.

Furthermore, waiting for OP to provide their code, whilst it might assuage some fears of 'they are just asking us to do their homework', is almost entirely useless in order to answer the question: Generally for algorithmic complexity issues, there is no simple tweak to an algorithm that isn't fast enough to make it fast enough. One must toss pretty much all the work out and start from scratch.

It might clarify matters, but the question as stated is clear enough; RobbyCornelissen's question can be easily answered just by careful reading and the slightest amount of imagination: Of course the exercise intends for you to suss out: "If the storekeeper sells an item, that means the store keeper now has 1 less of that item". Thoroughly disappointed in the vote-to-closers here.

Bit of a shame to let an answer go to waste. @user352805 - it's here https://pastebin.com/9va3Z804 - awaiting re-opening.

@rzwitserloot So the price of an item goes down as its remaining quantity goes down? Is that the interpretation?

@RobbyCornelissen That's what the question says, yes, and fits with the provided example. If I could speak to the designer of this question I'd tell them to rewrite it; 'it is a store' does not mesh with 'the price of an item is how many there are' - in fact, the opposite is how we intuit prices if anything (the more rare it is the higher the price should be). But, the question as stated is not ambiguous. That is indeed the correct interpretation.

I'd vote to reopen if  OP edited the question to show some code... It's not worth firing shots in the dark otherwise.

@MarsAtomic It's an algorithmic complexity question; not a single line of what they wrote will remain in the 'fix'.

@RobbyCornelissen Yes, the price is always equal to its remaining quantity. So the price goes down by one every time one is sold. I added a word to my description to hopefully make that clear.

I already voted to reopen as well. Just waiting for one more vote.

Your code is incomplete; in particular, it seems to be missing a main() function and at least one import. Please [edit] your code so it's a [mcve] of your problem (including any necessary inputs, but preferably not needing any), then we can try to reproduce and solve it. You should also read [ask].

@rzwitserloot , For the exquisite simplicity of your solution, you deserve a medal, and thank you for the explanation.

Here is a solution using a TreeMap.  It works as follows.

compute a frequency count of all the items.
then, get the last item (most expensive) from the map
add to revenue.
adjust that item's frequency down by 1 since to reduce number of that items availability at that price.
if (it is 1, remove it) from the map.
now increment the frequency of item-1 or create a new entry if it doesn't exist.
continue until m == 0

Additional logic is included to throw an exception if the inventory exceeds the desired sales.  One could also just return what was computed with available items.  It depends on what is required.
public static long getMaximumAmount(List<Integer> arr, int m) {
    TreeMap<Integer, Integer> inventory = arr.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(a -> a, b -> 1, Integer::sum,
                    () -> new TreeMap<>()));
    long revenue = 0;
    while (m > 0) {
        if (inventory.isEmpty()) {
                  throw new RuntimeException("Insufficient items to meet sales");
        }
        Entry<Integer,Integer> e = inventory.lastEntry();
       
        int item = e.getKey();
        int remaining =e.getValue();
        revenue += item;
        if (e.getValue() == 1) {    // remove it as
            inventory.remove(item); // no more remaining
        } else {
            inventory.put(item, remaining-1); // update
        }
        // create new entry or increment existing
        // don't update if item will be <= 0
        if (item > 1) {
           inventory.compute(item-1, (k,v)->v == null ? 1 : v+1);
        }
        m--;
    }
    return revenue;
}

This seems to work for a large range of values and sales in sub second times.

Thank you so much! This works really well and well within the timing constraints. Part of me still wonders if there was any way to do this without some type of HashMap.

sorting a list of 10^5 integers is a matter of a millisecond. If the limit is '4 seconds', that's effectively a free operation. More usually with challenges like these, what you're really worrying about is something called algorithmic complexity; usually stated in big-O notation. Sorting is O(n * log n) {n = size of input}, and generally the turning point is O(n^2) - anything slower than that is usually 'too slow' and anything faster is usually 'fast enough', with anything on the line.. a tossup. This is all.. stuff that takes 5 years of university to fully master, and Stack Overflow isn't the best place to post a 1000 page book, so generalizations will have to suffice.
Once we have a sorted list, this algorithm becomes very easy indeed. After all, you want to sell that item you have the most of, and that's at the front of the list.
We do need to take into account that selling that item doesn't make that item's stock disappear completely; it merely subtracts 1. The 'fastest' way to do take care of that is to realize that if continuing to sell the item that starts off with the highest stock is not correct, the algorithm to fix that is easy.
Imagine you have as input 10,8,8,7. You sell the 10, you sell the 9 that becomes, you sell the 8 that becomes - so far so good. But you should not sell the 7 that it became. Realizing this is very easy: You only have to look at the next item in the store, and you only have to remember that you have 'n' number of 7s left in the store once you run out of 8s.
However, that's a bit of coding, and there's an easy way out that is likely acceptable: Simply remove the number from the store and add it right back. Removing a single item from a TreeSet is O(log n); so is adding. We're going to add/remove m items where m is the 'you get to sell THIS many items' which is also bounded by 10^5 which is quite a small number, so, that's O(m * log n). Assuming n and m are of the same general magnitude (it's all 'at most 10^5 as you explained it), then's O(n*log n) to sort it and O(n*log n) to run the algorithm; constant factors don't count, so that's O(n * log n + n * log n), which is O(2 * n * log n) which is.. just O(n log n) again: The algorithm only became slower by a constant factor which is irrelevant (to make that realistic: Because you can just toss some cents at an IAAS provider for a faster CPU which will outpace a constant factor. You can not do that for an algorithm that is e.g. O(n^3) (tossing more input at the problem makes the time required to solve it like the curve y = x^3, with 'size of input' on the x axis and 'time taken' on the y, and if you look at y = x^3, that's a very steep line - money can't fight that line. It can fight y = x, or in this case, y = 1.
Putting that together is borderline trivial:
List<Integer> itemsAvailable = readThisFromTheInput();
int sales = readThisAsWell();

var items = new TreeSet<Integer>(itemsAvailable);
long answer = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < sales; i++) {
  int v = items.pollLast();
  answer += v;
  items.add(v - 1);
}

System.out.println(answer);

(TreeSet keeps its contents sorted inherently.)

Thank you for this detailed explanation! However, I tried running your code and didn't get the results I expected. It seems like TreeSet only maintains one instance of each value. So for the example I provided, it yielded 10+9+8+7+6+5=45 instead of getting 55.

@user3525805 yes, good point, you need guava's Multiset, or use a HashMap<Integer, Integer> that maps a value to the # of items in the shop with that amount-in-stock value.

If you change the TreeSet to a PriorityQueue(Comparator.reversed())  and then add the collection it should work as required.  Everything else should be identical based on my test.   Use PriorityQueue.poll() for obtaining the item.
